# On the multiplicative structure in spectral sequences.

Tags: homological-algebra, spectral-sequences, reference-request, at.algebraic-topology

Let $f\colon X \rightarrow Y$ be a continuous map of sufficiently nice
topological spaces (say, smooth manifolds). Let ${\cal F}=(\dots\rightarrow
F_i \rightarrow F_{i+1}\to \dots)$ be a bounded complex of sheaves of vector
spaces over a given field on $X$. It is well known that there exists
a spectral sequence $E_{r}^{p,q}(\mathcal{F})$ converging to the cohomology
sheaves of the push-forward $R^\bullet f_*({\cal F})$ (in the derived
category) such that the first term of it is equal to
$$E_1^{p,q}({\cal F})=R^qf_*(F^p).$$

Now let us have one more complex of sheaves of vector spaces ${\cal G}$
on $X$. The claim I am interested in is the following one: **There
exists a canonical morphism of the tensor product of spectral
sequences of ${\cal F}$ and ${\cal G}$ to the spectral sequence of ${\cal F}\otimes
{\cal G}$.**

After I talked to few experts in homological algebra and algebraic
geometry and made some google search, I got an impression that this
fact is a folklore and basically well known to experts. I would need
a reference to this fact.

Comment: Have you tried the book of Godement, "Topologie algébrique et théorie des faisceaux"?

Comment: @Mark Grant: yes, I did. I could not find it there too.

Comment: I would guess that once you work out all the details yourself, the need for a reference will magically disappear (cf the experts you asked)! (Sorry for the annoying comment :)

Comment: @Mark Grant: In fact I need to use this fact in a paper, potential readers of which will not be experts in homological algebra or algebraic geometry, but analysts and possibly differential geometers. In these communities the above fact is not a common knowledge. So some background reference would be helpful.

Comment: It is certain true in general! As for references, the only thing
I can suggest at the moment is Voisin's "Hodge theory and complex...II" pp 113-115. This is worked for $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients, but it's better than nothing. 
(By the way, it is an $E_2$ spectral sequence.)

Comment: Also have you checked out Bredon's "Sheaf theory", section IV.6.5?

Comment: @Donu Arapura: Thanks. I have checked pp. 113-115 in Voisin's book. Apparently she deals with a different spectral sequence. To compute the push-forward of a complex of sheaves there are two different spectral sequences. They come from two different filtrations on a bi-complex of injective sheaves resolving the given complex. 
(Also in my case I have described E_1 rather than E_2.)

Comment: @Mark Grant: Bredon in section IV.6.5 deals with the Leray spectral sequence. This is not what I mentioned. I need one of the so called hypercohomology spectral sequences, see wikipedia 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperhomology_spectral_sequence

Comment: Is this fundamentally a different question from the convergence of a spectral sequence of algebras to a desired algebra?

In re. your last remark, the hypercohomology s.s. is asserted on p.515 of "A User's Guide to S.S." By McCleary; two methods of proof are suggested --- composite functor s.s. OR a double complex of injective objects whose total complex has some desired homology.

Comment: @some guy on the street: Perhaps it depends on what you mean by "fundamentally different". To me it looks rather different. But perhaps for experts in homological algebra/alg. geometry the two situations are very similar modulo "common knowledge". 